# How many ways can a person select $3$ out of $10$ math questions while selecting at least one of four geometry questions?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A person needs to select 3 out of 10 math questions and will have to select at least one geometry question out of 4 available, in how many different ways can he select his questions?

I tried: There are 4 ways to choose the required geometry problem, and ${9\choose 2}$ to select the other 2, so my answer is $4 {9\choose 2} = 144$, but my textbook says the answer should be $100$, what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: The person could have picked multiple geometry questions to study.  Your count incorrectly applies some significance as to which of the possibly multiple geometry questions being studied was the "first" one picked to be studied.

Comment: Compare this to the problem where the student needs to select $10$ out of the $10$ questions to be studied where they need to select at least one geometry question out of 4 available.  By your logic, there would be $4\binom{9}{9}=4$ different possibilities... but simple reasoning should tell you there is only the one possibility.  For a corrected approach, either break into cases based on how many geometry questions were studied and add... or approach indirectly and subtract away those where you studied no geometry problems.

Comment: $\binom{4}{1}\binom{6}{2}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{1}+\binom{4}{3}\binom{6}{0} = \binom{10}{3}-\binom{6}{3}=100$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you're over counting. The long answer is:

You want to choose at least one geometry problem. There are two main approaches, one shorter than the other. Starting with the longer approach first:

The number of ways of choosing at least 3 geometry problems = number of ways of selecting exactly 1 + number of ways of selecting exactly 2 + number of ways of selecting exactly 3

So its:
$$\sum_{i=1}^3 \binom{4}{i}\binom{6}{3-i} = 100$$

The shorter way is:
Consider all the ways of selecting 3 problems, and from that, subtract the number of ways of selecting no geometry problems (because you always select at least 1):
$$\binom{10}{3} - \binom{6}{3} = 100$$

Note that in your working, you're over counting (for example note that picking one geometry problem is a subset of picking two geometry problems). I'd suggest looking into the principle of inclusion and exclusion if you want to follow your line of reasoning.